# Zend Framework 2 & jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework2

How does one go about displaying a controller action inside of jquery modal dialog?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you get the AJAX Call to your Controller running? Where is your concrete problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you'll need your Javascript to load a url via ajax, this will depend on which kind of modal you are using etc, there's a ton of libraries out there. I will assume you are using the basic JQuery UI dialog Modal.

Example Link

```
<!-- this points to your action below.. -->
<a class="some-link" title="title here" href="mycontroller/test">testing</a>
```

Example Javascript (quick example found on google, many examples out there..)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-link').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
            });
    });
});
```

Now you need to make sure your action doesn't render the main layout when providing the content for the modal via the ajax request.

Here's a really simple method of doing that by replacing the base layout with an empty view for ajax requests. This isn't the best method but it's the simplest for this case ;)

Example Action

```
public function testAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->layout('application/layout/ajax-layout');
    }

    return new ViewModel(array()); // ..
}
```

application/layout/ajax-layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->content ?>
```

Comment: AH! `isXmlHttpRequest` is what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, if you'd have provided your code and specified your question with "How to disable layout on ajax request" or such thing, i would have bitched around much less ;) It's all about asking the right question ;)

Comment: I am a programmer. Programming is first and foremost about problem solving. To be honest, if I have a clear grasp of the question, I generally don't need to ask it. Sometimes it is the question that eludes us and that we need help with.

Comment: If you don't need a layout for ajax requests you can use the following code to prevent rendering:      $request   = $this->getRequest();
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this kind of code http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
inside the  just display your action

Otherwise it's about to open an url into your modal it's like that http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/