# Where to put the modal layout and how to fill it with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have got the following question.
I have got an application built in ZF2. In some pages I have got a grid with some tabular info. Each line has got a button which should open a bootstrap modal and populate it with dynamic forms and data.

Now here is my question. I want to have a plain modal with no content available everywhere and fill it with dynamic content. I don't want to define my base modal everywhere.

I have seen some information in this link [Zend Framework 2 & jquery modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192702/zend-framework-2-jquery-modal-dialog) but it doesn't totally answer my question because where do I put the basic modal layout?

Comment: Not sure if I'm completely clear on what you're looking for, but it seems like you just want some re-usable html + js right? You could define a partial and just render the partial in every view that you need the modal dialog.

Comment: It answers part of my question. B/c how would I load the content of the modal dynamically?

Comment: I would put the generic part of the modal markup/js in the partial and then load the content using javascript. This dataloading javascript would be custom for each view where you use the modal.

Answer (score 3):

The way i do it is. on the ZF2 default layout i have the modal i want to load with dynamic data, i have set a variable for the title of the modal and a variable for the content. I use it to provide a message to the users when they save data to db successfully or if that fails. So inside my controller action when the page loads i create a session of that message and sent it to the layout see below example:

```
$t_session = new Container('msg');
$t_session->msg = 'Access Denied...';//body
$t->msgheader = 'Warning!';//title
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users', array());
```

when the redirect happens to the users route

```
//seesion modal for access denied
        $mysession="";
        $t_session = new Container('msg');
        $mysession = $t_session->msg;
        unset($t_session->msg);
        $this->layout()->mysession = $mysession;
        if(isset($t_session->msgheader)){
            $mysessiontitle = $t_session->msgheader;
            unset($t_session->msgheader);
            $this->layout()->mysessiontitle = $mysessiontitle;
        }
```

as you see above i pass that session message to the default layout with

> $this->layout()->mysession = $mysession;

and to load the modal i use this code.

```
<?php if($this->mysession != ''){?>

        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#idofmodaltoload').modal('show');
            });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

So if the body msg of modal is passed from some action to the layout thus not being empty i use JQuery to load that modal. I hope this helps.

Comment: But in this way tou have the popuo available everywhere even in places where you don't need it. I would prefer to use the partial

Comment: Instead of writing extra code to each place you need it. You Can always get the current controller with $controller = $this->params('controller'); or the current action with
$action = $this->params('action');. And finally pass the current controller or action to the layout and add an if statement saying to which action or controller the modal will be poping up

Comment: If you want to load your modal only for some controller say the IndexController then on the default layout you check if the user is currently at IndexController and if yes then the modal will be available to popup. If the user is within the actions of another controller the popup is not available.

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of a view helper and a partial - Although my 'dynamic content' is 99% of the time a form.

The view helper:

```
class Modal extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $template = 'base-module/widget/modal';


    public function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->template;
    }

    public function setTemplate($template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function setOption($name, $value)
    {
        switch($name) {
            case 'template' :
                $this->setTemplate($value);
            break;
            default :
                parent::setOption($name, $value);
        }
    }

    public function __invoke($title = null, $content, $target)
    {
        if (null !== $title) {
            return $this->render($title, $content, $target);
        }
        return $this;
    }


    public function render($title, $content, $target)
    {
        $partial = $this->getPlugin('partial');

        return $partial($this->template, array(
            'title'   => $title,
            'content' => $content,
            'target'  => $target
        ));
    }

}
```

The modal's default markup is set with the view script path `$template`

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <?php if (! empty($this->title)) : ?>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $this->title; ?></h4>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="modal-body" data-action="<?php echo $target; ?>">
                <?php echo $this->content; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-submit">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the variables here; `$title`, `$content` and `$action`. The `$action` is the URL that the modal will submit to when the 'save changes' button is clicked.

The JS looks like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-modal', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        $container = $($this.data('container')),
        target     = $this.data('target');

        if (! target) target = $this.attr('href');

        if (! target) return;

    var isXmlHttpRequest = true;

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : target,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $this.attr('disabled', true);
            $this.find('i').hide().end().prepend(loading);
        },
    }).done(function(response){

        $container.html(response);

        $container.find('.modal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        }).modal('show');

    }).fail(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {

    }).always(function(){

        isXmlHttpRequest = false;

        $this.attr('disabled', false);
        $this.find('img').remove().end().find('i').show();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.modal-submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this       = $(this),
            $modalBody  = $this.parent().parent().find('.modal-body');
            $form       = $modalBody.find('form');

    $form.prop('action', $modalBody.data('action'));

    $form.submit();
});

$(document).on('submit', '.modal-body form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this      = $(this),
            $elements  = $this.find('input, select, button, textarea'),
            $container = $($this.data('container'));

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type       : 'POST',
        dataType   : 'json',
        url        : $this.prop('action'),
        data       : $this.serialize(),
        beforeSend : function() {
            $elements.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            if (response.content) $container.html(response.content);

            closeModal();

        } else {
            if (response.content) $this.parent().html(response.content);
        }

        if (response.messages.length) {
            notifyAll(response.messages);
        }

        if (response.redirect) {
            redirect(response.redirect);
        }

    }).always(function(){
        $elements.prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Lastly just render the content in the required view script

```
// Create the URL target
$target = $this->url(
  'route/path/name',
   array(),
   array('query' => array('format' => 'json'))
);

// Render the modal using the view helper
echo $this->modal(
    'The modal title',
    $this->form($this->form), // Use the form view helper to set the modal content
    $target
);
```

Comment: Hey I have this as my link: <a href="/admin/productvariant/showForm/1" class="popup" data-container="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a> But after my ajax call is finished It comes into the "done" function but it doesn't show my modal